# Struts 2 and JDK 17 numbers in locale

Tags: java, internationalization, struts2, struts, java-17

With struts `6.3.0.1` and jdk 8 the below generates `1, 2, 3,`

```
     <s:iterator begin="1" end="3">
                <s:property value="top"/>,
     </s:iterator>
```

By changing to jdk 17 It generates `۱, ۲, ۳,` ( these are Persian numbers for `1, 2, 3,`)

I set the   `struts.locale` to `fa_IR`

```
<constant name="struts.locale" value="fa_IR" />
```

The site is Multilanguage and the `i18n` interceptor is used.

It may be a good feature but the site is built in the way that it works with English numbers. Anyway, is it any way that I can have numbers in English regardless of locale

I tried to fix it by `session.setAttribute(Config.FMT_LOCALE, new Locale("en", "US"));`  but no luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To print English numbers you should change a `Locale`. But you only print em in the `<s:iterator>` tag. You should know how to get a current [`Locale`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html) from the [`ActionContext`](https://struts.apache.org/maven/struts2-core/apidocs/com/opensymphony/xwork2/ActionContext.html) in JSP.

Then you save a current locale to the variable before you change it

```xml
<s:set var = "old_locale" value = "%{#context.locale}" />

<!-- then change a current locale -->

<s:set var = "%{#context.locale}" value = "%{new java.util.Locale("en", "US")" />

<!-- print numbers with a new locale -->

<s:iterator begin="1" end="3">
    <s:property value="top"/>,
</s:iterator>

<!-- then return a current locale back -->

<s:set var = "%{#context.locale}" value = "%{#old_locale}" />
```